# Julia Delaunay triangulation hangs indefinitely

Tags: julia, delaunay

I am trying to get to grips with Delaunay triangulation in Julia. I am trying the following test code.

```
using VoronoiDelaunay
a = Point2D[Point(rand(),rand()) for i in 1:6]
tess = DelaunayTessellation()
push!(tess,a)
```

On inputting the final command into the REPL, the code seems to hang indefinitely. I have tried several times now and left it running for a long time, but at no point has it finished. Does anyone know if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [`VoronoiDelaunay` package currently limits input points](https://github.com/JuliaGeometry/VoronoiDelaunay.jl#current-limitations) to a range of `[1 + eps, 2 - 2*eps]`. I was able to get your code to run with this change:

```
a = Point2D[Point(1 + rand(),1 + rand()) for i in 1:6]
tess = DelaunayTessellation()
push!(tess,a)
```

Following [the example in their README](https://github.com/JuliaGeometry/VoronoiDelaunay.jl#building-a-tessellation), you can also use the built-ins `max_coord` and `min_coord`, which should be more robust than my first attempt:

```
width = max_coord - min_coord
a = Point2D[Point(min_coord + rand() * width, min_coord + rand() * width) for i in 1:6]
```

Note I'm assuming you meant `DelaunayTesselation` as `DelaunayTriangulation` does not appear to be a method provided by the package.

My result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's very useful. I did indeed enter the function name incorrectly in my original question, which serves me right for typing it out rather than copying and pasting. For future reference I was also able to find this discussion regarding this issue https://github.com/JuliaGeometry/VoronoiDelaunay.jl/issues/38